# Serilog configuration is only partially respected

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, serilog

I use Serilog.AspNetCore 3.2.0 and Serilog.Sinks.File 4.2.0 in an ASP.NET Core 3.1 project and I have the following configuration in my `appsettings.json`:

```
"Serilog": {
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "MinimumLevel": "Verbose",
        "Enrich": "FromLogContext",
        "Args": {
          "path": "Server1_.log",
          "rollingInterval": "Day",
          "buffered": "false",
          "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Verbose"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

I configure my services with the following:

```
.UseSerilog(
(hostingContext, loggerConfiguration) 
   => loggerConfiguration.ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration)
)
```

When I change the output file name, it changes accordingly.

I use the folowing code for test:

```
Log.Information("Starting...");
Log.Debug("Starting...");
Log.Warning("Starting...");
```

This is the output:

```
2020-06-03 12:05:23.372 +02:00 [INF] Starting... 
2020-06-03 12:05:23.372 +02:00 [WRN] Starting...
```

**Debug and Verbose levels are ignored.**

How can I add lower levels to the log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON schema isn't quite right; `MinimumLevel` and `Enrich` are top-level:

```
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": "Verbose",
    "Enrich": ["FromLogContext"],
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "Server1_.log",
          "rollingInterval": "Day",
          "buffered": "false",
          "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Verbose"
        }
      }
```

Further examples [in the README](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration#serilogsettingsconfiguration--).

Comment: Yes, you are right, I missed that. Thank you, it works now.